# How can I use PHP function/vars into a ini file with ini_parse_file

Tags: php, ini

I currently use a *.ini(.php) file in order to make the configuration of my script easy-to-use, I use `ini_parse_file()` in order to store the values ​​from the ini file into a variable as array, like this :

```
$settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini.php");
print_r($settings);
```

However, I'm encountering a problem, I would like to use `getvar()` function into this .ini.php, I tried like this (please do not laugh) :

```
;<?php return; ?>
[SQL]
host = localhost
user = root
password = root
dbname = laravel

[SYSTEM]
name = TEST-456
url = http://<?php echo getenv('HTTP_HOST'); ?>
version = 1
```

Obviously, it don't work and return a pretty warning :

> Warning: syntax error, unexpected '(' in settings.ini.php on line 10 in /www/attempt.php on line 2

As you had (I think) already figured out, I'm asking if such a thing is possible to do, and if it's possible how can I do this ?

Comment: No, it is not possible, the ini file format doesn't support this use case. What you could do oth is move this logic to your configuration object (assuming you have a single point of access and don't parse the file around your application).

Comment: @nietonfir Thanks for comment, i'm gonna try ;)

Comment: Many frameworks use a syntax like `%HTTP_HOST%` and when processing the config, they search the values for %<anything>% and check if anything is a constant (using [defined](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)). Maybe that is an approach you want to take as well since it is commonly used already.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Great idea, gonna look for this way